# Search with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, hyperlink

I am getting search lists but i cannot click it to go to the respective pages of the items. What I should do ? I need to add hyperlinks to those options. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];

$array = array();

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

$db=mysql_select_db("medical",$con);

$query=mysql_query("select * from medicine where med_name LIKE '%{$key}%'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{

$array[] = $row['med_name'];

}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: In which graveyard did you dig up this piece of code? It must have been buried there for more than 10 years. Nobody should use `mysql_*()` functions anymore. I recommend *PDO*, starting with **prepared statements**.

Comment: Oh, `mysql_*`. Yay. Should probably move on to `mysqli_*` or **PDO** if you want your queries to be secure (with prepared statements of course), and **not** using a deprecated extension.

Comment: What is the question, how to make links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of ways about going about this, but the easiest solution is to add the hyperlinks to the array. You can store the pages as links in the database, but I'm going to **assume** the pages are all called `[med_name]`.html. To link to those, you would have to craft the hyperlink around the name itself:

```
$array[] += "<a href='" . $row['med_name'] . ".html'>" . $row['med_name'] . "</a>";
```

This will give you an array with indexes like:

```
<a href='field1.html'>field1</a> 
<a href='field2.html'>field2</a>
```

Please keep in mind that MySQL has **long** since been deprecated. It's deprecated in PHP 5.5, and outright removed in PHP 7. I'd really recommend switching over to **[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: To clarify, it's not MySQL that's been deleted, but `mysql_query`, which is just one way to access MySQL.